# How can I build an app with XCode 13.4 for iOS 16 Devices?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios15, xcode13, ios16

I'm working for a company which has an application in the AppStore. We need to test iOS 16 before release. I can not build the app iOS 16 devices with XCode 13.4. If we got build with firebase and run the app in iOS 16 but the app stuck into splash screen and wasn't crash. So I can not found the problem.

Is there any way to log my code without using remote database?

Comment: You will need to build it from the Xcode 14 Beta, that way you will be able to debug it properly.

Comment: There is an explanation how to run iOS16 with xcode 13 if you want. Go to this link and hope it will be what you need. Best regards. [ https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport ]

Answer (score 26):

- Enable developer mode in your iOS16 beta device.
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device
- Download iOS16 version for Xcode DeviceSupport in your Mac.
  https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport
- Unzip
- Copy and paste unzipped folder

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

- Connect your iOS device to Mac
- Run Xcode
- Check Xcode > Window > Devices and Simulators

Comment: Didn't work for me on iOS 16.2 on a 2013 MacBook and Big Sur. "Failed to prepare device for development. This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility."

I use a cloud mac mini with VirtualHereServer to forward the development device via USB, thats not free though.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck finding the problem using the latest Xcode 14 beta, available here:

https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/

It sounds like you might be using a cloud build service to build your app. To debug this issue, you'll want to use Xcode running locally and attach the debugger. Once you figure out what's going wrong, try building on Xcode 13.4.x, then get your cloud build service working.